# How to delete the "Just" in customized haskell show function

Tags: haskell

I have a custome data structure called pitch with 2 variables note and octave. I need to convert a string to a pitch, so that I wrote a function that takes a String as input and Maybe Pitch as return value since there might be some invalid input. Then I customized my show function, when I tested it in ghci, it showed "Just A2" (A2 is the pitch value). Here is my code:

```
data Pitch     = Pitch { note :: Char, octave :: Int }deriving (Eq)

toPitch :: String -> Maybe Pitch
toPitch str 
    | strlen == 2 && (note >= 'A' && note <= 'G') 
           && (octave >= 1 && octave <= 3) = Just (Pitch note octave)
    | otherwise = Nothing
    where 
        strlen = length str
        note   = head str
        octave = digitToInt (str!!1)

toString :: Maybe Pitch -> String
toString (Just pitch) = [note pitch] ++ [(intToDigit (octave pitch))] 

instance Show Pitch where
    show pitch = toString (Just pitch)
```

And below is the test result:

```
*Main> let pitch = toPitch "A2"
*Main> show pitch
"Just A2"
*Main>
```

Can someone tell me how to remove that Just in the show function? Much appreciated!

Comment: What if it's `Nothing` there?

Comment: Hint: use a `case` statement. Or, write a new function that pattern-matches.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the  Maybe wrapper if  we are sure that there is value  in that variable? In my project, another function that take the [Pitch] as input rather than [Maybe Pitch].

Comment: @MingoPan You can't just remove it, because it might be a `Nothing` - `Maybe` is more than just a wrapper! You need monads. Have you read Learn You A Haskell?

Comment: @MingoPan you can "remove" it by using the fromJust method in Data.Maybe.  However, this is not a total function and it will throw an error if you feed it a Nothing.

Comment: If you are sure that it is a Just then you should improve your code and return the `Pitch` instead of a `Maybe Pitch` at that point.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, thank you guys!

Comment: @AJFarmar Why did you delete your answer? It's exactly the answer I wanted to write after reading the question.

Comment: @DanielWagner I realised that the main problem was that the asker was `show`ing a `Maybe Pitch`, not that they had written `show` incorrectly. If you truly think it's useful, I'll reinstate it.

Comment: @AJFarmar Ah, of course! I would have written the exact same wrong answer. =P

Comment: I'm not sure when `show (toPitch "A2") ==> "A2"` would be of more interest than `show <$> (toPitch "A2") ==> Just "A2"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a string representation of the `Maybe Pitch` value is what you really want. Instead, you want a `Maybe String` value, indicating that *if* you really have a `Pitch` value, you can get a `String` representation, but if you have `Nothing`, you still get `Nothing`. This just means a use of the `Functor` instance for `Maybe`.

This means moving your logic into the `Show` instance for `Pitch`:

```
instance Show Pitch where
    show pitch = note pitch : intToDigit (octave pitch) : ""
```

You typically aren't interested in a value of `Maybe Pitch` itself; you are interested in the `Pitch` value that you *might* be able to extract from it. That means you usually just want to lift `show` to get a `Maybe String` value.

```
>>> show (Pitch 'A' 2)
"A2"
>>> toPitch "A2"
Just (Pitch 'A' 2)
>>> fmap show (toPitch "A2")
Just "A2"  -- not "Just A2"
```

---

To be clear, if `toPitch` returns `Nothing`, that's somewhat of a show stopper: it's not obvious that there's a suitable default value to use instead. Using `Maybe Pitch` instead of a partial function like

```
toPitch :: String -> Pitch
toPitch str 
    | strlen == 2 && (note >= 'A' && note <= 'G') 
           && (octave >= 1 && octave <= 3) = Pitch note octave
    where 
        strlen = length str
        note   = head str
        octave = digitToInt (str!!1)
```

simply forces the rest of your code to accommodate the possibility of failure in a graceful fashion, rather than just crashing with a run-time error when `toPitch` fails to return a value of type `Pitch`.

---

You might also want to use a parser library to implement `toPitch`. For example

```
import Text.Parsec

toPitch :: String -> Either ParseError Pitch
toPitch str = parse pitchParser "" str
    where pitchParser = do
            note <- oneOf "ABCDEFG"
            octave <- satisfy (`elem` "123")
            return $ Pitch note (digitToInt octave)
```

The parsing process is a little more straightforward, and you'll get something (slightly) more descriptive than `Nothing` in the event of a parser failure.